# how to compile Libsmscout Library on Windows?

Tags: c++, cmake

While I try to Run CMake for the Library https://github.com/Framstag/libosmscout

I get an Error on CMake Line 250

```
create_private_config("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/privateinclude/osmscout/private/Config.h" "OSMScout")
error: Unknown CMake command "create_private_config .
```

OS: Windows 10 ; IDE: Qt Creator

Comment: Can you please provide the **full** error message? Saying "*CMake Line 250*" does not describe **which** CMake file this error occurred in...

Comment: Usual reason for "Unknown CMake command" errors is running `cmake` not for the **top-level** project source directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From browsing the repository, it appears the error is occurring in the `libosmscout/libosmscout/CMakeLists.txt` file at [line 250](https://github.com/Framstag/libosmscout/blob/ec4037823e57f26daab0db6317d155ced4b9d104/libosmscout/CMakeLists.txt#L250). CMake defines this function in `libosmscout/cmake/features.cmake`, a file which is included from the *top-level* CMake file. Try running CMake using the commands below, ensuring CMake starts from the **root directory** of the repository (same directory containing the `appveyor.yml` file):

```
cd C:/path/to/your/repo_root
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

The `appveyor.yml` file has some example configurations (e.g. Visual Studio 2015, x64) that have been tested with this project.

Comment: Thanks So Much, That was so correct, I tried to build the Higher path CMake, it worked with Visual Studio 2019, but it didn't work with Qt !